# Linux command without directory name

Tags: linux, command-line

Beginner at linux here, is there a way to create a permanent link between a command and the directory it's within. I've got XAMPP installed and to start i'm using:

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Is there a way to change this so instead I can just type

```
lampp start
```

Without changing the directory (i.e like how normal commands are executed in linux)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using Bash.

The way you would do this is by adding the directory /opt/lampp to your PATH variable:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/lampp/
```

To retain this change permanently, you could add the above line to your .bash_profile file. As demonstrated already, there are multiple answers to this kind of problem. I'd recommend dedicating a bit of time to reading about Linux in general, it will save you time in the long run. A decent Bash tutorial is here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash.html

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I've always set my `PATH` with `PATH=$PATH:/whatever/dir` instead of `PATH=${PATH}:/whatever/dir`. Is there any difference between using the curly brackets and not?

Comment: There's actually a lot you can do with curly braces in Bash. When referring to variables, I use them to delimit the variable contents from the string it's being attached to. Your example works because of the : and the / in between PATH and the rest of the content. If (for example) you tried to join the string like: `PATH=$PATHwhatever/dir`, you'd run into problems.  For other cool stuff you can do with curly braces, search for "curly brace expansion" or play around with tricks like: `${COLOUR:-blue}`

Comment: In this case the curlies are not needed, but it is always safe to add them, and not always safe to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create an alias. Edit the file `~/.bashrc` and add a new alias, such as :

```
alias startlamp='/opt/lampp/lampp start'
```

Then, you can type startlamp instead of /opt/lampp/lampp. Please note that this alias is only valid for your own user, and not everyone that uses your computer.

This does not create a link, though, unlike Travis' command.

Answer (score 1):

Sure is. Try this:

```
ln -s /opt/lampp/lampp /usr/bin/lampp
```

`ln -s` creates a symbolic link to `/opt/lampp/lampp` from `/usr/bin/lampp`. The reason that we put it in `/usr/bin` is because that is where all your standard UNIX commands will be found, such as "ls" and "rm".

Now you can type `lampp start` no matter what directory you are in!

Note: you will probably need to run the above command as superuser, or root.

Comment: Brilliant works perfectly, thanks to all other answers as well. Thank you.

Comment: I would not recommend polluting system directories such as `/usr/bin`, as it could mess thing up. These directories are probably managed my you package manager. The `/opt` directory was added for you to add your own stuff to. There is also the `/usr/local` sub-structure, it has its own `bin`, `lib`, `etc`, etc. They are all empty waiting for you to put stuff into (for application that want to be put into this structure). For self contained applications, use `/opt`, and set the PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you'd want to either make a symlink (as Travis points out) point to the app from a directory which is within your path, or add `/opt/lampp` to your path. If you want it for your account only, you can put it into your shell's rc file in your home directory (`~/.bashrc`, for instance), or in the system shell config (`/etc/bash.bashrc`) which would make it apply to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making a bash alias.

Login with a non root account and open a terminal window
After you get the terminal window open, use vi to open ~/.bashrc

> `vi ~/.bashrc`

In vi, either look for the aliases or just go to the end of the file
Press the 'i' key (without quotes) to enter insert mode
Type the following into your .bashrc file

> `alias lampstart='/opt/lampp/lampp start'`

Press ESCAPE to exit insert mode
Type the following to save the .bashrc file and quit vi

> `:wq!`

At the terminal, type the following command to reload your .bashrc file

> `bash`

now type `lampstart` in your terminal, and lamp should start.  You could actually name the alias whatever you want, i just used the alias lampstart because it seemed logical.

Answer (score 0):

I like to put all my custom commands in a `~/bin` folder which I add to my path.

In `~/bin/lampp`, I would have:

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Make sure you `chmod a+x ~/bin/lampp`. Then you can run `lampp` anywhere and will have the desired behavior.

The advantage of this method is you have a central location for all your own commands and aliases.

**CORRECTION:**

This works better for more complex commands. For more basic commands, a symlink instead of a script is better, as in Travis' answer.